# I have an Imac and enabled SSh, cannot connect from other places. What is it?

Tags: ssh, imac

So, I have an iMac and a windows device. I wanted to connect over SSH to it, and it worked, but I was in same house. Now, I'm in my parents home, and connot establish connection. Please help.

IP : 192.168.1.17 through port 22

Comment: What address are you trying to connect to, and how did you determine it?

Comment: 192.168.1.17 with port 22. I found it in preferencies i think

Comment: check fw. then 'ssh user1@192.168.1.17'

Answer (score 4):

The IP address you found is "private" – meaningless outside your home LAN. The new network that you're visiting might use the same 192.168.1.x addresses but they'll mean something completely different than in your home network.

To reach a computer over Internet, it needs to have a "public" (i.e. Internet-wide) address, but most ISPs do not have nearly enough IPv4 addresses to assign to every device anymore – at most they'll assign one to your router and that's it (and some don't even have enough for that).

- If you're lucky, your home *router* has a public IPv4 address, and you need to configure the "port forwarding" feature in the router, so that you could SSH to the router's IP address and it would relay connections to one of your LAN's internal addresses.

  When at home, visit the router at 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.254 and 1) look for the "WAN IP address" reported, 2) look for the "Port forwarding" or "Virtual server" settings.

  If the "WAN" address *does not* start with `10.` or `172.16.`–`172.31.` or `100.64.`–`100.127.` or `192.168.`, then that's the router's public address and you can try configuring "port forwarding". If it *does* start with any of those, it's still a private address (see next section).
- If you're unlucky, your home LAN has no public IPv4 addresses at all (if the ISP has enabled CGNAT due to the address shortage); in that case "port forwarding" will never work because you can't even reach the router itself. (Well, it *might* still work if both places use the same ISP, but that's not guaranteed.)

  When you have no public address at home, you'll need to use some kind of relay service, most commonly a VPN (something like Tailscale or some other "mesh VPN").
- In some cases the iMac might also have an IPv6 address – there *are* enough of those that it can have its own public address. Check whether the iMac **and** the place you're visiting have an IPv6 address that starts with `2xxx:` – if both networks have IPv6, then you might be able to use that for SSH.

  (Usually you will still need to configure the home router to allow incoming connections through, but this time more likely under "firewall" than "port forwarding".)

Answer (score 0):

192.168.X.X (`192.168.0.0 /16`) is the IP range provided by your router, what we usually call "LAN" (local area network). You also have an public IP which is shared between all devices connected to your LAN.

Being in another house means being connected to another LAN and having a different public IP.

A common way to SSH from outside of your LAN, is to setup **port forwarding**.

- [How to access home ssh server from outside via the Internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360840/how-to-access-home-ssh-server-from-outside-via-the-internet)
- [Security concerns](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107987/connect-two-computers-with-ssh-in-a-home-lan/1108044#1108044)